# Set p4client from command line in perforce in a jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, perforce

I work on a jenkins pipeline to build a project loaded from perforce.

In concurent build, Jenkins setup the working workspace as `pipeline-workspace@2`
Problem is perfoce forbid `@` character. Due to that the creation of the workspace/client in perforce fails since the p4client is by default using the path of the local workspace.

I would like to change the `p4client` to a custom value in a non-interactive way.

I ve read the `p4 client` doc bur can't figure out how to do it.

I am able to to it with the interactive prompt by setting by hand the p4client and the //depot streams value but i would like to it on the fly by my jenkins script.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the workspace delimiter by setting the [hudson.slaves.WorkspaceList](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/system-properties/) Java System Property in Jenkins.

`-Dhudson.slaves.WorkspaceList=_`

This will change your delimiter from the default @ to _